# Что такое iterator в java?

Tags: java

Ребят. Всем привет. Объясните доступным языком, что это - iterator? А то пишу этот код и не понимаю, что это, зачем это?

Comment: Это интерфейс, который позволяет обойти все элементы коллекции. В общем-то всё. Остальное зависит от конкретной реализации. Советую поглядеть исходники итераторов, например для ArrayList.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Iterator` - если по-простому, то это метод, с помощью которого получается следующий элемент коллекции - ну, как бы некое правило обхода элементов коллекции/массива данных.

Формально это интерфейс `Iterator`, который содержит 3 метода:

- `hasNext()` - проверяет, есть ли следующий элемент;
- `next()` - возвращает следующий элемент;
- `remove()` - удаляет текущий элемент.

Пример: допустим, в классе 20 детей. Преподавателю надо всех по одному вызвать к доске. Есть, грубо, 2 способа:

1. Вызывать по алфавиту - как указаны в классном журнале.
2. Вызывать по порядку, как они сидят.

В терминах Java это разные итераторы: первый итератор - по классному журналу, второй итератор - по местам на партах. Можно придумать и более хитрые итераторы - например, по дате рождения, по желанию и проч.

Comment: iterato.remove();  - удаляет текущий элемент в iteratore или элемент в колекции.

Comment: Вообще-то итератор это никак не метод...

Comment: @smackmychi - капитан очевидность )) - речь идет о методе как о способе, но не как о методе в Java - различайте контекст.

Comment: В коллекции. Поскольку это интерфейс, то реализация итератора привязана к коллекции конкретной. В самом итераторе не хранятся элементы коллекции, он просто их оттуда достаёт и отдаёт вам. Это как посредник между вашим кодом и данными в коллекции.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, что поделать, контекст автором установлен. Не говоря уж про то, что он даже название интерфейса написал.